# Vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$: justify the inequalities $a\cdot b\le |a\cdot b|\le |a| |b|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, inequality

Let $a, b$ two non null vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. During last calc class we used the inequalities
$$a\cdot b\le |a\cdot b|\le |a| |b|$$,
where $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The latter inequalities should be clear (it should be Cauchy-Schwarz), but where did the first one come from?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is trivial and true of any real number: $x \le |x|$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (including dot products).

This follows immediately by definition of absolute value:

$$|x| := \begin{cases}
x, & x \ge 0 \\
-x, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

Consider proving the inequality by cases.